# Support for adding custom Gremlin DSL in AWS Neptune and Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am wondering if AWS Neptune and Azure Cosmos DB support adding custom Gremlin DSLs?

Also, do they support inline lambdas?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to add an answer below, but to avoid the question being closed by a moderator, I recommend editing the question to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom DSLs are really just wrappers you build around existing Gremlin steps. As such, these are evaluated client side, and therefore should work just fine if you are using Amazon Neptune as your graph database. You can just follow the examples for whichever Gremlin client driver you are using such as [these instructions for the Gremlin Java client](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-dsl).

Amazon Neptune does not support in-line code (closures/lambdas). Looking at [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support) I do not believe CosmosDB supports lambdas/closures either.